# numpy - pretty printing

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of strings. When a value in the array is undefined, None is printed as you would expect. Is it possible to provide a default value for None values?

e.g. in the following I want "_" instead of None

```
[[None B C]
 [M None O]
 [X Y None]]
```

would become

```
[[_ B C]
 [M _ O]
 [X Y _]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution might be to transform your array to string first and then replace the string None afterwards, for example if your matrix is `a`:

```
print(str(a).replace('None','_'))
```

you can also define a function:

```
def printarray(a): 
    print(str(a).replace('None','_'))
```

Comment: The problem is that this forces all the strings to not contain 'None', or they will be modified.

Answer (score 7):

You might also consider using a masked array:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([[None, 'B', 'C'],
          ['M', None, 'O'],
          ['X', 'Y', None]])
print(x)
# [[None B C]
#  [M None O]
#  [X Y None]]

x=np.ma.masked_equal(x,None)
print(x)
# [[-- B C]
#  [M -- O]
#  [X Y --]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has the ability to create boolean arrays from testing conditions, and then use those boolean arrays with the bracket notation to change selected values. For a string array `foo`:

```
is_none = (foo == None)
foo[ is_none ] = "_"
```

(Yes, I know that normally you should use `is` when comparing with `None`, but since you know your input is a string, and I don't think Numpy provides a vectorized `is` statement, `==` will be just fine.)